# Magento 2 : get report of currency exchanged rates

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In Magento 2 Is there any way to get a report of currency exchanged rates?

Comment: Hi Prasad, what data would this report show?

Comment: I need to get a history of updated currency rates.

Comment: ok, well assuming you use fixer.io then https://fixer.io/documentation#historicalrates